# How exclude !Ref tag from check-yaml git hook?

Tags: python, git, yaml, pre-commit-hook

There is a `serverless.yaml` file which contains line like that:

```
VpcId: !Ref MyVpc
```

Yaml files are validated by `check-yaml` `git` hook which invoked by `pre-commit` command. So the `pre-commit run --all-files` run is failed with error:

```
could not determine a constructor for the tag '!Ref'
  in "serverless.yml", line 172, column 29
```

Is there a way to configure `check-yaml` to skip this error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
hooks:
- id: check-yaml
  args: ['--unsafe']
```

should do the trick. It just checks syntax instead of attempting to load the YAML.

Comment: This works, however, `Using this option removes all guarantees of portability to other yaml implementations`.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific example above, which suggests a CloudFormation template, you can also consider [cfn-python-lint's pre-commit hook](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/#pre-commit).